# univariate nonlinear optimization with quadratic constraint in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, quadratic, nonlinear-optimization

I have a quadratic function f where, `f = function (x) {2+.1*x+.23*(x*x)}`. Let's say I have another quadratic fn g where `g = function (x) {3+.4*x-.60*(x*x)}`

Now, I want to maximize f given the constraints 1. `g>0` and 2. `600<x<650`

I have tried the packages `optim`,`constrOptim` and `optimize`. `optimize` does one dim. optimization, but without constraints and `constrOptim` I couldn't understand. I need to this using R. Please help.

P.S. In this example, the values may be erratic as I have given two random quadratic functions, but basically I want maximization of a quadratic fn given a quadratic constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you solve `g(x)=0` for `x` by the usual quadratic formula then that just gives you another set of bounds on `x`. If your `x^2` coefficent is negative then `g(x) > 0` between the solutions, otherwise `g(x)>0` outside the solutions, so within (-Inf, x1) and (x2, Inf).

In this case, `g(x)>0` for `-1.927 < x < 2.59`. So in this case both your constraints cannot be simultaneously achieved (`g(x)` is LESS THAN 0 for `600<x<650`).

But supposing your second condition was `1 < x < 5`, then you'd just combine the solution from `g(x)>0` with that interval to get `1 < x < 2.59`, and then maximise `f` in that interval using standard univariate optimisation.

And you don't even need to run an optimisation algorithm. Your target `f` is quadratic. If the coefficient of `x^2` is positive the maximum is going to be at one of your limits of x, so you only have a small number of values to try. If the coefficient of `x^2` is -ve then the maximum is either at a limit or at the point where `f(x)` peaks (solve `f'(x)=0`) if that is within your limits.

So you can do this precisely, there's just a few conditions to test and then some intervals to compute and then some values of `f` at those interval limits to calculate.